# react cannot properly filter objects

Tags: reactjs

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Home = () => {

    const [search, setSearch] = useState({
        category: '',
    })

    const [filteredPreviews, setFilteredPreview] = useState([])

    const filterSearch = e => {
        let filteredPreviews = previews // filterPriviews is equal to the sample data
        setSearch({...search, ...{category: e.target.id}}) // updating category
        if(search) {
            if(search.category === 'All'){ // if category is All, then show all previews
                setFilteredPreview(previews)
            } else {
                filteredPreviews = previews.filter(preview => preview.category === e.target.id)
                setFilteredPreview(filteredPreviews)
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            
            <section className="main-nav">
                <div className="main-nav-content">
                    <ul className='categories'>
                        <li><a onClick={(e) => filterSearch(e)} id='All'>All</a></li>
                        <li><a onClick={(e) => filterSearch(e)} id='Action'>Action</a></li>
                        <li><a onClick={(e) => filterSearch(e)} id='Survival'>Survival</a></li>
                        <li><a onClick={(e) => filterSearch(e)} id='Horror'>Horror</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>

        <section className="games">

            {filteredPreviews.map(preview => (
                <div className="game">
                        <h3>{preview.title}</h3>
                        <p>{preview.category}</p>
                    </div>
            ))}
        </section>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

**Sample Data**

/* Sample Data */

```
const previews = [
        {
            title: 'Red Dead Redemption 2',
            category: 'Survival'
        },
        {
            title: 'FEAR',
            category: 'Horror'
        },
        {
            title: 'Battlefield 1',
            category: 'Action'
        }
    ]
```

This code just filters the games by their category, it works fine but there is a problem where the previews do not update when the user clicks once on a category, they have to click twice on a category in order for the previews to update, I cannot find a solution so I came here for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're calling setSearch with the id of the filter the user has clicked, and then trying to conditionally test the search state, which hasn't been updated yet. You could change `if(search.category === 'All')` to `if(event.target.id === 'All')` but a better solution might be store all of your previews in state and filter them each render based on the new reality (in this case, which filter we've selected).

```
const PREVIEWS = [
  {
    title: "Red Dead Redemption 2",
    category: "Survival",
  },
  {
    title: "FEAR",
    category: "Horror",
  },
  {
    title: "Battlefield 1",
    category: "Action",
  },
];

const Home = () => {
  // This is where we'll store the currently selected filter, just like you had it
  const [search, setSearch] = useState({
    category: "All",
  });
  // This is where we'll store our entire set of data, in this case our previews
  const [previews, setPreviews] = useState(PREVIEWS);

  // All the event handler will do now is set the new filter criteria...
  const handleClick = (searchCategory) => {
    setSearch({ ...search, category: searchCategory }); // updating category
  };

  // ...and we'll use our currently selected filter to "derive" our displayed previews using the filter() function!
  // if there were performance issues or other props that would cause rerenders and we didn't want to recalculate, we could useMemo() this value or rethink our approach
  const filteredPreviews = search.category === "All" ? previews : previews.filter((preview) => preview.category === search.category);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <section className="main-nav">
        <div className="main-nav-content">
          <ul className="categories">
            <li>
              {/* We don't have to pass the event to these handlers - we can pass anything we want! In this case, we'll pass the filter name to make it readable */}
              {/* We could even pass this handler inline, as in onClick={() => setSearch(...)} /*}
              <a onClick={() => handleClick("All")} id="All">
                All
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleClick("Action")} id="Action">
                Action
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleClick("Survival")} id="Survival">
                Survival
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleClick("Horror")} id="Horror">
                Horror
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className="games">
        {filteredPreviews.map((preview) => (
          <div className="game" key={preview.title}>
            <h3>{preview.title}</h3>
            <p>{preview.category}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```